# Non-alignment of vector and raster layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, alignment

I have a vector map layer, raster climate data and added a delimited text points layer. My problem is that the raster extent does not quite match the edge of the vector map, and as a result, some of my coastal data points are being excluded when I sample raster values.

I've added a screen shot (hopefully it will be clear from this). I have made sure that the CRS projections are the same. Is there anything else I can do?

[image]

Comment: How do you know they are misaligned? The pixels are very large, maybe your raster dataset just dont match exactly with your vector layer